# Loading a library via CFFI under swank/slime

Tags: common-lisp, slime, cffi

I'm seeing an odd behaviour when loading shared libraries under slime/swank.  From a command line REPL:

```
* (asdf:load-system :cffi)
T
* (cffi:load-foreign-library "s:/src/lla/lib/libopenblas-0.3.21.dll")
#<CFFI:FOREIGN-LIBRARY LIBOPENBLAS-0.3.21.DLL-518 "libopenblas-0.3.21.dll">
```

all good.

The same from emacs/slime/swank just hangs.  The workaround is to go to the `*inferior-lisp*` buffer and press enter.  After doing that the load unhangs and things proceed normally.

Any ideas?  I'll report this to the slime folks if it turns out to be a bug, and it looks like it to me, but before I do thought I'd check here first to see.  This is on MS Windows, if that has anything to do with it.